# Please synonymise [nuxtjs] with [nuxt.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There is the main tag [nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt.js) with thousands of questions, then there is [nuxtjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxtjs) with just 404 questions and no usage guidance. Please synonymise. I see that [nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt) already goes straight to [nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt.js).

Comment: 141 questions tagged with `nuxtjs` [are also tagged with `nuxt.js`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=nuxtjs)

Comment: Weird - how did we get two of them?

Comment: Wait [the tags synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Active) already says [that the two are synonyms](https://i.imgur.com/fUyKNDJ.png). From January.

Comment: @VLAZ Weird! It also says `[tag:nuxt]` was renamed today. Perhaps there's a bug on that page?

Comment: @KenY-N to be honest, I don't know how to read that table. I'm not sure what "# of renames" is supposed to track. The nuxtjs -> nuxt.js has zero, for example. Similarly, I don't know what the "Last renamed" is, either.

Comment: Just for info, the "# of Renames" is the total occurrences *the source tag is used after the synonym was created and approved*, and thus renamed to the target tag. The "Last renamed" is... when the last it happened. //cc: @VLAZ

Comment: The reason why there were questions still tagged with 'nuxtjs' even though they are already a synonym is that the synonym doesn't propagate to older questions unless a mod *merges* the tag. //cc: @VLAZ